# How to stop the <apex:form> onSubmit event from triggering when html5 validation kicks in?

Tags: visualforce, validation, commandbutton, html5, form

I have this simple form

```
<apex:form onSubmit="alert('submit!');">
   <apex:inputText id="a" value="{!a}" required="true"/>
   <apex:commandButton action="{!signup}" value="b"/>
</apex:form>
```

And whenever I don't fill anything in the `<apex:inputText>`, the HTML5 validation triggers, the form is not actually submitted and I would expect the onSubmit event to **not** trigger. However, contrary to my expectations, it does... How to prevent that? Or how to know whether a submit actually happened or not?

Comment: This isn't HTML5 validation; required is an attribute checked during the postback to the server. In fact, onsubmit would fire anyways, because it's meant to be a pre-flight check to see if we should allow submission. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: well I do see the HTML5 popup with 'Please fill this field' so I assume HTML5 validation is working somewhere. Also, there is no actual network call to the server, so there is no real submission, right? Anyway, what I want is to disable the commandButton while submitting. But if I do that now in the onSubmit event, then the button becomes disabled even when there is a validation error. And then the user has no way to submit the form anymore... :-)

Comment: Your code verbatim works in my developer org; the alert doesn't happen if the validation is triggered. Maybe it's something else going on with your page?